# Sami API doc generator update error: "The '/' directory does not exist ('/')"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using v4.1.4 of this fork of the fabpot/Sami repo, since the original isn't supported any longer.  The forked repo doesn't accept issues, so I'm posting here in hopes of some ideas on the cause of the issue.

https://github.com/blueend-ag/Sami

I keep getting this error when trying to run the update command using the .phar file.

```
php ./sami_v4.1.4.phar update ./sami.config.php -v

Updating project

In FilesystemLoader.php line 106:

[Twig\Error\LoaderError]

The "/" directory does not exist ("/").
```

The strange thing is this only occurs when using the .phar file. If i extract the phar & run the command using the sami.php file from the extracted directory, it runs perfectly fine. Any ideas what could cause the issue? The issue only occurs with the phar from this fork. The phar from the original repo works fine as well.

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
php ./sami_v4.1.4.phar update ./sami.config.php -v
 Updating project

In FilesystemLoader.php line 106:

  [Twig\Error\LoaderError]
  The "/" directory does not exist ("/").


Exception trace:
 () at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php:106
 Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->addPath() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php:87
 Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->setPaths() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php:45
 Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->__construct() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/Sami/Sami.php:161
 Sami\Sami->Sami\{closure}() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php:118
 Pimple\Container->offsetGet() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/Sami/Sami.php:135
 Sami\Sami->Sami\{closure}() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php:118
 Pimple\Container->offsetGet() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/Sami/Sami.php:80
 Sami\Sami->Sami\{closure}() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php:118
 Pimple\Container->offsetGet() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/Sami/Console/Command/UpdateCommand.php:53
 Sami\Console\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:908
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:269
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://F:/xxx/sami_v4.1.4.phar/sami.php:13
 include() at F:\xxx\sami_v4.1.4.phar:9
```

sami.config.php

```
use Sami\Sami;
use Sami\RemoteRepository\GitLabRemoteRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Sami\Version\GitVersionCollection;

$dir = dirname(__DIR__,1) . '/my-application/app';

$iterator = Finder::create()
    ->files()
    ->name('*.php')
    ->exclude('node_modules')
    ->exclude('resources')
    ->exclude('database')
    ->exclude('config')
    ->exclude('routes')
    ->exclude('bootstrap')
    ->exclude('storage')
    ->exclude('tests')
    ->exclude('vendor')
    ->in($dir);

$versions = GitVersionCollection::create($dir)
    ->add('release/v0.1', 'v0.1')
    ->add('release/v0.2', 'v0.2')
    ->add('release/v0.3', 'v0.3')
    ->add('release/v1.0', 'v1.0')
    ->add('release/v1.1', 'v1.1')
    ->add('release/v1.1', 'v1.1')
    ->add('develop', 'develop')
    ->add('master', 'master');

return new Sami($iterator, [
    'versions' => $versions,
    'theme' => 'default',
    'title' => 'API Docs',
    'build_dir' => __DIR__ . '/docs/api/%version%',
    'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/docs/api/cache/%version%',
    'remote_repository' => new GitLabRemoteRepository('test/test', dirname($dir), 'https://gitlab.com/'),
]);
```

**Debug taken so far:**
 - Use absolute dir paths in config
 - Extract & recompile phar file
 - Change location of `sami_v4.1.4.phar` and `sami.config.php` to various directories (root, subdirectory, sibling directory, parent directory).